# Android Garbage collector Runs on Main Thread?

Tags: android, garbage-collection

**Example:**
 Lets say ideally that object is garbage collectable (activity changed orientation and strong reference to object lost) but not yet disposed. So line 2 will return true. Is there any way that object get disposed while execution is on line 3? Or it wait until it finishes?

```
new Thread {

       WeakReference item= new WeakReference(object);

       void method(){
2      if(item.get()!=null)
3          item.get().getName();
      }
}
```

Comment: @Sanoop Irrelevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have strong reference to an object then that object is not eligible for GC.

There is no way strong referenced object will get disposed in code between null check and next line... or any other line as long as you can access that `object` reference. Only if you set that object reference to null, or you assign another object to that reference, previous object can be garbage collected if there are no other references pointing to it.

On the other hand, when you are dealing with weak references (of any kind) first you have to take strong reference out of weak reference wrapper and then you can safely use that strong reference further on (after you check it is not null, of course). If you don't take strong reference, object in weak wrapper can vanish at any time.

**Wrong usage - object can be collected between null check and `getName` call**

```
if(item.get()!=null)
   item.get().getName();
```

**Correct usage - taking strong reference for further processing**

```
Object object = item.get();
if(object!=null)
   object.getName();
```

Comment: You didnt answer my question. Also i said ideally, the object maybe  is weak referenced so its garbage collectable if the strong reference is lost somehow .

Comment: there is no sight of weak reference in your question. If you have weakly referenced object then you first have to obtain strong reference from it and then use that strong reference.

Comment: My primary question is  Does GC run on the Main Thread of android's process or is a worker Thread?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. It is not about on which thread it runs... because it does not work like that. GC stops all code execution until it is done. But it can run at any time... and it will not collect any object that is reachable with any strong reference.

Comment: Please consider that not every reader will look into the edit history, so it’s not a good idea to start the answer with “There is no way object will get disposed in your code between null check and next line” when the question’s only code example is that using the weak reference, where the object can get garbage collected in-between.

Answer (score 4):

First of all Garbage Collector does not run on what you think as your proccess's main thread.
When looking from Operating System's prospective, GC may run either in main thread of the virtual machine that runs your application. Or it can run on a new thread.

But from Java prospective, GC does not run on any of your application's thread. The thread that run GC is neither your Java main thread nor a Java thread accessible to you.

From the prospective of your Java code, the main thread and all other thread are stopped (removed from scheduler) while GC runs. This is not always true though. But that is up to the VM implementation. But you must always assume that all your Java threads, including main thread are stopped while GC runs.

So, to precisely answer your question, **

> Yes, your week reference can become null in the second line.

**

Your code can get a NullPointerException in line three.

Because line 2 and 3 are two seperate non antomic operations. It is possible that GC can cick in after executing line 2 , stop execution of all your threads, do garbage collection , and then resume all your threads causing a NullPointerException to occur at line 3.